# Can't parse properties of complex type

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I'm working with eBay's finding service, and everything works fine except parsing unitPrice. It says [here](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/types/UnitPriceInfo.html):

> eBay uses the UnitType and UnitQuantity

So in my UnitPriceInfo.java I have this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UnitPriceInfo", propOrder = { "type", "quantity", "any" })
public class UnitPriceInfo
{
    @XmlElement(name = "UnitType")
    protected String type;
    @XmlElement(name = "UnitQuantity")
    protected Double quantity;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
```

But still, `UnitPriceInfo` objects are instantiated but they always have both type and quantity fields to null.

Do I need to change the type from String and Double to `UnitType` and `UnitQuantity`? If not, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements are named `type` and `quantity`, like this:

```
  <unitPrice>
    <quantity> double </quantity>
    <type> string </type>
  </unitPrice>
```

You should change your annotations to `@XmlElement(name="type")` and `@XmlElement(name="quantity")`.

Comment: Turns out it was failing for other reason, but you were right.

Answer (score -1):

can you please change class name from UnitPriceInfo  to "unitPrice" OR give annotated name "unitPrice" for class name .

Comment: It's not adviced to start with lowercase for a class name in java.